# Emailing Campaign Mistake Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, utm

I would like to have information about the tracking of emailing campaigns on google analytics.

I created a new URL and I filled in the different fields "UTM source" "UTM campaign" etc...

I also activated the data in real time but despite all this, I cannot get information and data concerning my emailing campaign, can you help me and tell me where the problem comes from?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about programming problem. I think it would be on topic for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ if it had sufficient detail in it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GA free, the data takes 24-48 hrs to be visible in reports. For GA premium the SLA is up to 2 hrs. Source/Medium reports are generated based on the landing page URL, so make sure the email CTA's are tagged with right landing pages with right UTM's